# Is it possible to mount other cloud storage platforms like Degoo, as we mount google drive?

Tags: dataset, google-colaboratory, cloud-storage

I would like to keep a backup of large dataset like chictopia10K( 40GB )           in cloud. But google drive has 15G limit. Degoo is offering 100GB free space. So I would like to know, whether it is possible to mount Degoo, similar to google drive.

Comment: I don't know anything about Degoo, but 100G of Google Drive storage [is $20 a year](https://one.google.com/about). That's probably the simplest solution.

Comment: I too would like to know of a way to use datasets hosted at Degoo with Google Colab. Not sure if former provides APIs for that